# Trying to make animated nav bar in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im attempting to make a navigation bar with Jquery. the idea is that you click on the navigation button and several links(in the form of divs) will slide out. However, i am unable to get the initial click action to work. Currently im just trying to move the #Home button to the left 100px after you click the #clickme button.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src = "jquery-2.0.1.js"></script>
<script>
$("#clickme").click(function(){
    $("#Home").animate({left: 100} , "fast");
});


</script>
<style type="text/css">
#Nav {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
    top: 268px;
    left: 530px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.Button{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:0;
    background-color:#693;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Nav">
    <div id="Home" Class = "Button">Home</div>
    <div id="About" Class = "Button">About The Internship</div>
    <div id="Meet" Class = "Button">Meet the Interns</div>
    <div id="Request" Class = "Button">Request an Intern</div>
    <div id="clickme" Class = "Button">Navigation</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel. There are plenty of menu plugins out there that are accessible. [Not everyone uses a mouse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait 'till your dom is ready + you've the wrong selector.

.ID is for Classes (css)

#ID is for actual ID's

```
$(function(){
  $("#clickme").click(function(){
    $("#Home").animate({left: 100} ,"fast");
  });
})
```

This should work..

Answer (score 1):

In addition to stackErr's answer:
'fast' should be passed as a string.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/xt57a/

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
    $("#Home").animate({left: 100} ,'fast');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id selector is incorrect. 
Your code should be:

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
    $("#Home").animate({left: 100} ,'fast');
});
```

this shouldnt matter but script tag should have the type attribute since you are not using HTML5:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have made this correction and it still doesnt work properly. updated code is above

Comment: @stackErr you're missing quotes $("#Home").animate({left: 100} ,"fast");

Comment: Christian I think waiting for the dom to load won't solve the issue. The selector was wrong and he passed 'fast' as a variable (which of course is undefined) instead of a string

Comment: I made the quotatuion correction above and it still wont slide over properly

Comment: @JonasGrumann that's correct, I've fixed it in my solution. Thanks mate :)

Comment: @Jpm61704 than please mark one of the answeres as the final solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be with the selector. id must be used with `#` not with `.`

try

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
    $("#Home").animate({left: 100} ,fast);
});
```

you can place this code at the bottom before `</body>` using scripts at the bottom of the page makes page faster & executes when dom is ready. otherwise wrap the codde with `$(function())`